# New-AzWebAppSSLBinding : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to use `New-AzWebAppSSLBinding` to upload and install a pfx ssl certificate to Azure, however, I'm getting an error:

```
"New-AzWebAppSSLBinding : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'".





PSVersion 5.1.14393.2515 
PSEdition Desktop 
BuildVersion 10.0.14393.2515 
CLRVersion 4.0.30319.42000
```

I'm able to successfully get information about my resources via:

```
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $azResourceGroup
Get-AzWebApp -Name $azWebAppName
```

After successfully connecting to the SPN via:

```
$azpsw = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($appID, $azpsw)
$azConnect = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -TenantId $tenantID -Force
```

I execute the following command:

```
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName $azResourceGroup -WebAppName $azWebAppName -Name $azName -CertificateFilePath $azCertPath -CertificatePassword $azCertPsw -Verbose
```

This results in error:

```
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
```

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve my issue by appending the `-Debug` parameter to New-AzWebAppSSLBinding. My hostname did not match the cert subject name.

This resulted in me setting the correct HostNames via:
`Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $azResourceGroup -Name $azWebAppName -HostNames @("server_name.azurewebsites.net","server_name.my.domain.name")`

The first entry has to be there, otherwise Azure PS will throw a Warning.

My issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the SSL certificate was not there in the resource group, which caused the issue. I had a step in the script to upload the new certificate to the resource group with "New-AzResource" but strangely that was not working. To solve the issue I have manually uploaded the certificate to one of the app services which will upload the certificate to the resource group level and the "New-AzWebAppSSLBinding" works well